# Problem with convertion from excel to utf8, and return de information in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a problem with a piece of code. I need to transform same information in a excel cell and VBA transform the characters.

Example:
The code is the following:

```vb
    Option Explicit
    Sub EliminarEspaciosCeldas()
        Dim celda As Range
            For Each celda In Selection
                celda.Value = Trim(celda.Value)
                celda.Value = StrConv(celda.Value, vbProperCase)'Here is the problem transformation
        Next
    End Sub
```

For example did transform the letters
My language is Spanish (UTF8)

```
'ñ=˜   á=Á    é=   í="   ó=Ž  ú=Ú  Á   É   Í=›   Ó    Ú
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the problem though?

Comment: Mi problem is when the macro run change de words inside de excel. Transform for example the word "Martín" in "Mart"n" or "Balón" in "BalŽn". It's clearest?  in the line StrConv(celda.Value, vbProperCase) is the problem....

Comment: I get `martín` ==> `Martín`  and `balón` ==> `Balón`    Did you type in your text or is it copy-pasted from somewhere?